# Add extras to Intent of application which has been paused by Home button

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget, widget, android-activity

I have a main application and home screen widget which able to launch that application.
Widget put some extras to Intent to pass initial data to application.

```
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putString(AppWidgetConfigureActivity.EXTRA_ITEM, modeName);              

Intent modeIntent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.my.app");

modeIntent.putExtras(extras);
modeIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);                 
context.startActivity(modeIntent);
```

In OnCreate method of that Application I get this extras:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
Intent intent = this.getIntent();
String mode = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_ITEM);
...
}
```

All is going fine if application is not launched or stopped by pressing Back button.
But if Application has been paused by Home button it re-launched from my widget with old extras, it starts from onResume method, not from onCreate (it's obvious fact) and at that point Intent of activity has old extras but not that extras which I put to Intent from widget.

How to pass extras from widget to Application which has been paused by Home button?

Comment: If you want to pass another time in onCreate, you must destroy the activity.
onResume not allowe intent catching because is a callback of resuming something that was just created and had just used intent.

If you want to reload the activity you can try to use 'this.finish' when go back

Comment: No, I don't want to destroy activity or somehow interfere standard workflow of application. I want to stay in common android's workflows and interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

i am not quite sure what you want here but let me try..
you can use `getIntent()` to get the `Intent` in `onResume()` but i am not sure if you can still grab the extras there. 
however you could just save the extras you get in the `onCreate()` method and set the content of your app in `onResume()` if you have to recreate something.
also take a look at `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()`.

```
String mode;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = this.getIntent();
    mode = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_ITEM);
    ...
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    setMode(mode);
}
```

Comment: Let me explain more straight my goal:
At first time widget runs application with some extras. Application started and onCreate method are called. At this point I get from Intent exact extras that I expect.
Then I press Home button, application paused (but not destroyed). Next I use widget to start again that application with some new extras. Application runs and onResume method are called. At this point I try to get new extras from Intent, but I got old extras which I put in Intent in very first time from widget.

Comment: this is correct, your app activity created in the first place will not get destroyed. not by home button, devie sleep or starting the activity again.

Comment: trying to be more precise: this is correct, your app activity created in the first place will not get destroyed. <i>(not by home button, devie sleep or starting the activity again)</i>... if you start it again from your widget with `startActivity()` you get a second instance of this activity and the first one will not get destroyed and will still be on the stack... so you maybe should kill the old one before starting it again - maybe with a flag like `clean_top` or `reorder_to_frot` or a other way

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution!
You just have to add one more flag to Intent.

```
modeIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

This flag (FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) clears current task stack and make visible new Intent's extras in onResume callback.

Comment: I too face same problem but in my case app is paused with home button and i am calling the app again from widget configuration activity  but above solution is not working for me